# Advantage of telling the Swift Compiler an object's type, instead of inferring?

Tags: ios, swift, variable-declaration

I have been doing Swift programming for a few months now and I have always been curious about this...

Is there an advantage to telling the Swift compiler the type of an object in its declaration?
I.e.`let image: UIImage = UIImage()`

Compared to NOT telling the compiler and having it infer the type at runtime. I.e `let image = UIImage()`

I would think it would be more efficient to tell the compiler the object type instead of having it infer the type. I know this question appeals to Objective-C syntax as well, so I'll add that in the tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There’s zero runtime efficiency difference between the two.  During compilation, Swift is inferring the type and writing it in for you.  But once compiled, the two statements are identical.

It’s purely a question of readability and, occasionally, compiler efficiency.

Readability because in the statement `let image: UIImage = UIImage()`, the double appearance of `UIImage` is just clutter.  And in cases of more complex types, it’s pretty much essential – no-one wants to write `let keys: LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<String, Int>, String>> = dict.keys` when they can write `let keys = dict.keys`.

Compiler efficiency because occasionally you’ll find that a particularly ambiguous type (literals of literals are notorious for this) where lots of overloads need to be resolved can compile a *lot* faster if you explicitly name the type on the left-hand side.  But this is just a question of how fast it compiles, not how fast it runs once it has compiled.

Answer (score 2):

From [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> It is rare that you need to write type annotations in practice. If you provide an initial value for a constant or variable at the point that it is defined, Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for that constant or variable, as described in [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

So It doesn't matter if you declare instance type or not.